# Django modeling, common base and one-to-many relationship

Tags: django, model

I'd like to create two similar models AlbumA and AlbumB.

Both of them will have songs.

```
class AlbumBase(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract=True

class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(AlbumBase)  # problem here

class AlbumA(AlbumBase):
    # with specific properties to A (DB fields)
    pass

class AlbumB(AlbumBase):
    # with specific properties to B (DB fields)
    pass
```

I don't think `Song` can have foreign key to `abstract base class`.

How should I model these relationships in django?

- EDIT

## 1. use ManyToManyField

Based on `arie`'s answer, I could define the album-song relationship on the other side, just careful with the names (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name)
Another difference is that, my original question has 1-Many relationship, and this answer is Many-Many.(I want 1-Many, but could live with M-M..)

```
class AlbumBase(models.Model):

    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")

    class Meta:
        abstract=True

class Song(models.Model):
    pass

class AlbumA(AlbumBase):
    pass

class AlbumB(AlbumBase):
    pass
```

## 2. multitable-inheritance

Or I could use multitable-inheritance like below.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    pass                        # not abstract

class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)

class AlbumA(Album):
    pass

class AlbumB(Album):
    pass
```

## 3. Generic foreign Key (based on Mark's answer)

```
class AlbumBase(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract=True

class Song(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, db_index=True, related_name='+')
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
    album = generic.GenericForeignKey()

class AlbumA(AlbumBase):
    pass

class AlbumB(AlbumBase):
    pass
```

Which one should I go with?
What are the questions that I should ask to pick among these solutions?

Comment: What are the specific properties? Different database fields, or is it python functionality?

Comment: If you're brave you could try a generic foreign key. Most people talk negatively about them or avoid them completely. But, unfortunately abstract classes are not very OO and are only meant for you to reduce code duplication. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Comment: @MarkGalloway: Oh I use generic foreign key all the time.. didn't know general consensus is against using it. Do you have any link (? can't think of better term here) to support your statement about GFK?

Comment: The problem with the multi-table inheritance is that you will incur extra table joins. Maybe this is not a noticeable performance hit for you. Hard to say.

Comment: I've just heard to avoid them from other developers IRL and here. But, I did find this post so maybe I should eat my hat. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333460/django-generic-foreign-keys-good-or-bad-considering-the-sql-performance

Comment: a nice helper for answer #2. http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager

Answer (score 0):

If you are deriving your models from an abstract class, its better to add information to these models directly.
you can rather try linking Song class to AlbumA and AlbumB.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really talking about *different classes* of Albums with distinct properties and database fields?

If you are only concerned about handling songs that differ from album to album, I see no need for an abstract base class and would rather model my models like this:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song)
    ...
```

Alternatively, if you are sure that you don't have songs that exist in the context of multiple albums (say compilations or best of-albums) you could also do this:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    ...

class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
```

From what you show and describe don't see any need for GFKs or inheritance.

It's simply a matter of (simple) relations.

Comment: I would do this as well. It seems strange to restrict a song to only one album if trying to model the real world.

Comment: ah.. that was the difference, actually I'm modeling blog - comment, I just thought the song/album is easier to grasp..

Comment: Even if you let songs point to albums there should still be not need for an abstract base class ... unless i missed something.